# Why can't typescript infer generic type parameter when one type parameter depends on another?

Tags: typescript

Let's consider the following code:

```js
type SomeFunc<Arg, ReturnType> = (data: Arg) => ReturnType;

function wrapper<T extends SomeFunc<R, any>, R>(callbackOne: T, callbackTwo: (id: number, data: R) => void) {}

const callback: SomeFunc<number, void> = () => {};

// Works fine when types are provided manually
wrapper<SomeFunc<number, void>, number>(callback, (id, data) => {});
// TypeScript can't infer correct type here
wrapper(callback, (id, data) => {});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgMQK4DsDGAeAggJwHMAaKAJQmFX3QBVwIA+KAXigAoATAQ2G4C4oBQgEpWzClRr1IAbgBQ8gGYZMwAJZx0UAO75uYSPmy0oEAB7AI6TgGdYiFKuxlS3dCEakyjdpm4ANgEARtyYANYA8ugQgrSk-kGhEbQ6cILs6pyC6KgIwRD4pDx8gmRiLMwAbnBZYgDeAL6KmFq2wFCJIWHhgvBIaFjYufmFpDVZzGzsFcxNCvIA9ItQAOpw+OH2SuoxugAW1lCgkPbc+NBg+HBVWRCcUAjuqIEBIPJ6BkbY-U5DIwUilAJpwvFAAYVfF1kuFSJlOMVeNxZlAmiIFMsoDIIDBMPh1GAOv50AByDq7JSFTobC5qY4MKCHC4ffSGQp+V4wuFZRF8FFohRAA)

As can be seen above, we have generic type parameter which is used in another parameter. In that case, TypeScript is not able to infer correct type automatically, even though it seems like it has all the info needed.

An obvious solution here is to remove `R` type param and instead rely on `T` for type of data: `data: Parameters<T>[0]`. However, `T` may be incredibly complex and extracting type would be quite difficult and brittle.

Why can't TypeScript do that and is there a better solution to this than mentioned above?

Comment: @jcalz, thank for the reply! Yes, that issue is what I was looking for, if you can post it as answer I'd be grateful! Based on the info in issue it seems like the best option here is to use workaround with intersections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't use [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) as inference sites for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments when calling generic functions.  It's a missing feature, suggested at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) but never implemented.

---

Type arguments are only inferred from function parameter types, and sometimes [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) from the return type.  So, in the call signature:

```
declare function wrapper<T extends SomeFunc<R, any>, R>(
    callbackOne: T,
    callbackTwo: (id: number, data: R) => void
): void;
```

`R` is inferred from the type of `callbackTwo` and that's it. The fact that `T` is constrained to `SomeFunc<R, any>` doesn't affect inference.  It only serves as a *check* on `T`, which means that if `R` isn't inferred how you want, then `T` is likely to fail the check.

---

The suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) to support using constraints as inference sites was discussed and eventually declined as unneeded once inference from [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) was improved enough to enable [a workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234#issuecomment-223627422).  The approach is to replace (or supplement) constraints at the declaration site like `X extends F<Y>` with intersections at the usage site like `X & F<Y>`.  In your example that would look like

```
function wrapper<T extends SomeFunc<R, any>, R>(
    callbackOne: T & SomeFunc<R, any>,
    // ----------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    callbackTwo: (id: number, data: R) => void
) { }
```

`T`'s inference is unaffected, but now `R` can be inferred from `callbackOne` and not just from `callbackTwo`, and your code works as desired:

```
const callback: SomeFunc<number, void> = () => { };
wrapper(callback, (id, data) => { }); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgMQK4DsDGAeAggJwHMAaKAJQmFX3QBVwIA+KAXigAoATAQ2G4C4oBQgEpWzClRr1IAbgBQ8gGYZMwAJZx0UAO75uYSPmy0oEAB7AI6TgGdYiFKuxlS3dCEakyjdvKgBUJjcADYhAEbcmADWAPLoEIK0xP6BwWGRMbQ6cILs6pyC6KgI4RD4pDx8gmRiLMwAbnAF8mIA3lAAvoqYWrbAQaERUdGC8EhoWNjFpeWkTQXMbOx1zB2dCvIA9FtQAOpw+NH2SuoJugAW1lCgkPbc+NBg+HANBRCcUAjuqEMg8noDEZsOMnFMZmUKlAFpwvFAIeVfOlhjFSPlOJVeNxVlB1iIFDsoDIIDBMPh1GABsF0AByAZnJTlIKHR5qG4MKBXR4A-SGcrsZGZaJogqYvg4vGbeTobhIWxgKLQZDqcy41IBW7QUGTHDCbyUah0BhLDhVARCIg4ySG4mbQJQFRYDRaXS84GmCxWGz2bXOVxQdyeby+dX2wYZEbxRJEqAAMgcEz9bg8XlD9sFI2yuQ4BSKJUhYvNtXE0OanFD7S6inTfSpQyFY0cOum+bmpcWrA4Eq6CntgL5+AF9ZGIoxUDN3c6+KghLg0W4-0UnSAA)